# RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service using Fotoapparat in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2, camera-view

Need help to resolve a **Fotoapparat** **library** issue.

```
io.fotoapparat.exception.camera.CameraException: Failed to open camera with lens position: io.fotoapparat.characteristic.LensPosition$Back@31c3b8a2 and id: 0
```

When I open the first time It will work correctly. But after that, I click on other tabs and then open camera screen It will display a blank white screen. I am using viewPager for that.

How did you initialize FA?

```
 mCameraView = view.findViewById(R.id.camera);
 fotoapparat = Fotoapparat.with(getActivity())
            .into(mCameraView)
            .previewScaleType(ScaleType.CenterCrop)
            .logger(new Logger() {
                @Override
                public void log(String s) {
                    Log.e("Camera", s);
                }
                @Override
                public void recordMethod() {

                }
            })
            .cameraErrorCallback(new CameraErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(CameraException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    fotoapparat.stop();
                }
            })
            .build();
```

FA version: 2.5.0

Devices/APIs affected: 19,20,21,22

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Like: more of your stack trace!